# How to get first date and last date from given month name and Year

Tags: asp.net

In my page I have on dropDown ddMonth and ddYear ...ddMonth shows jan,Feb,mar etc. ddYear as 2014,2015... . By using this How can I get the first date and last date from this 2 dropdown (ddmonth and ddYear) by using asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first date of always starts with 1 so you can create date using day as 1

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
```

For last date of month you can add 1 to month and subtract on day from it.

```
DateTime dt = (new DateTime(year, month, 1).AddMonths(1)).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: you cant do `month + 1`. you have to use function `AddMonth(1)` in case the month is 12.